# Disabling TouchPad on Ubuntu 18.04 (Temporarily)

Tags: ubuntu

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 on my System76 Oryx laptop.  The trackpad is very sensitive so I used to disable it using Fn+F1.  That is not working anymore in 18.04.  I looked around and found:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

When I set that it seemed to work for a second then reset...

```
$ synclient TouchpadOff=0
$ synclient | grep TouchpadOff
    TouchpadOff             = 0
$ synclient | grep TouchpadOff
    TouchpadOff             = 1
```

I also found:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
```

But that seems more permanent.  When I tried to set back to 1, it remains off.  Seems I need to reboot now to turn it back on.  I used to be able to toggle with Fn+F1.

Comment: You should ask that on askubuntu.com since SO is about programming question rather than OS configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to install [Touchpad Indicator](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

it will

- Disable / Enable touchpad with indicator menu or keyboard shortcut.
- Disable touchpad when mouse is plugged.
- Disable touchpad while
  typing.

and i think it will fix the "work for a second" problem

Hope it helps

Comment: a very useful utility & appears to work well in Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks

Comment: this works well for disabling the touchpad when my bluetooth mouse is connected, but does not seem to re-enable the touchpad when I turn the mouse off. Am I missing something? Maybe the disable while typing option is better for me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to disable the trackpad because of its annoying scrolling and clicking behavior (yeah, I know what happens when you assume: you make an ASS out of U and ME, but it wouldn't be the first time).

I, also, just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, and found my trackpad behavior suboptimal with seemingly random scrolling and mouse clicks even though I had disabled the scrolling and mouse click in the System Settings GUI.

Basically, I just wanted to be able to position the cursor with the trackpad and nothing else.   Here's what I found solved the problem.  First, get the device id from xinput:

```
% xinput list
```

You should see the trackpad with it's ID.  Mine looks like:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

with id=12. List the touchpad properites with the command:

```
%  xinput --list-props 12
```

The relevant properties are "Two-Finger Scrolling", "Edge Scrolling", and "Tap Time", with property IDs 314, 313, and 305 respectively.  Assuming your property IDs match mine, disable these with the commands:

```
% xinput set-prop 12 305 0
% xinput set-prop 12 313 0 0 0 
% xinput set-prop 12 314 0 0
```

and now your trackpad should provide only mouse pointer position.  If your property IDs are different then use yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Shortcut with the following command:

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "file='/tmp/touch-disable'; id=$(xinput | grep YOUR_DEVICE_STRING | grep -o 'id=[0-9]\+' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'); if [ -f $file ]; then xinput enable $id; rm $file; else xinput disable $id; touch $file; fi"
```

This command will toggle the the Pointer device.

**How to create the shortcut:**

1 - Open a Terminal and find the device:

```
$xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HOLTEK USB Wireless Device                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3075-002                      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]  <-- this is my touchpad
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

2 - Open Gnome-Settings/Devices/Keyboards Shortcuts
[Keyboard Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0EFD.png)

3 - Add new Shortcut by using the '+'-button
[Add Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEtiU.png)

4 - Copy descriped command and replace "YOUR_DEVICE_STRING". Example: "Synaptics TM3075-002"

5 - Name the Shortcut and set the define one

**Description:**

To toggle the Touchpad enable/disable we create a file in /tmp as marker we have disabled the pointer device. By the second execution we will remove the file, so we know the next time we the device is enabled. The state change is archived by the xinput enable/disable .

That means the command can be also as example:

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "file='/tmp/touch-disable'; id='Synaptics TM3075-002'; if [ -f $file ]; then xinput enable $id; rm $file; else xinput disable $id; touch $file; fi"
```

To be able to run this command, we can use the gnome-terminal withe the bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$ xinput list
// here you see the ID of the TouchPad
$ xinput disable ID
// Replce ID of the number of devic
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure we have the exact model of Oryx Pro from System 76 (model: orxp1). I have noticed the same issue that the "Fn+F1" keyboard shortcut stopped working since I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I have a solution that restored the keyboard shortcut behavior and it has made my life a TON easier.

First, I had to run the following command (that isn't installed on Ubuntu 18.04 for whatever reason):

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then reboot.

Once you're back up, the keyboard shortcut (Fn+F1) will be working again and will toggle correctly! Since I discovered this solution and saw that it worked flawlessly, I thought I'd share it here. Hope this helped!